# Install of cx_Freeze

Tags: python, linux, installation, cx-freeze

Hi I try to install **cx_Freeze** on my linux but I can't install it. I want to install it to convert my python app (.py) in an executable app.

I download the sources from this website : https://sourceforge.net/projects/cx-freeze/?source=typ_redirect and extract it in a folder.

I follow the install instructions by issuing in console `python setup.py build` and get the following error:

```
python setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 138, in <module>
    finder = cx_Freeze.ModuleFinder(bootstrap = True)
  File "/home/calbert/Téléchargements/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 160, in __init__
    self._AddBaseModules()
  File "/home/calbert/Téléchargements/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 187, in _AddBaseModules
    self.IncludeModule("traceback")
  File "/home/calbert/Téléchargements/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 678, in IncludeModule
    namespace = namespace)
  File "/home/calbert/Téléchargements/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 346, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)
  File "/home/calbert/Téléchargements/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 436, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "/home/calbert/Téléchargements/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 502, in _LoadModule
    self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)
  File "/home/calbert/Téléchargements/cx_Freeze-4.3.3/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 588, in _ScanCode
    arguments.append(co.co_consts[opArg])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Thank you for your help because I'm not a professionnal of programs installation in linux ;)

Answer (score 0):

cx_Freeze has been moved from sourceforge, you only find older versions there (which are presumably not compatible with your Python installation). The current source of cx_Freeze can be found [here on GitHub](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze).

cx_Freeze can also be installed from PyPI by issuing the command

```
python -m pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade
```

See the [entry page of cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) for the official information.